# ASP.Net Core: Issues with file uploads - file locking and 404's

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a controller method which uploads a file against specific interfaces.  Only 1 document per interface is allowed, the file name is always the same and thus overwrites the previous for that interface.  The file upload works fine the first time but on attempting to upload another to the same interface shortly after it can't because the file is locked.  I am handling this with a try but even so the page returns a HTTP ERROR 404.  How do I stop the file locking and why am I getting a 404? (Running locally)

Controller Method:

```
 public async  Task<IActionResult>  Documentation(DocUpload document)
    {
        if (document.Document != null)
        {
            // do other validations on your model as needed
            try
            {

                string fileName = "Interface-" + document.InterfaceId + "-Documentation" +
                                        Path.GetExtension(document.Document.FileName);
                string doucumentationPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "documentation");
                string filePath = Path.Combine(doucumentationPath, fileName);

                await document.Document.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
                string fileUrl = "~/documentation/" + fileName;

                document = new DocUpload();
                if (_context != null)
                {
                    Dictionary<int, string> interfaces = _context.Interfaces.OrderBy(x => x.InterfaceName)
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.InterfaceID, x => x.InterfaceName);
                    document.Interfaces = interfaces;
                }
                document.Message = "Documentation upload complete";
                document.InterfaceId = -1;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                document.Error = true;
                document.Message = "The has been a problem uploading the documentation:" + Environment.NewLine +
                                   e.Message;
            }

            //to do save to db   


        }

        return View(document);

    }
```

View:

```
    @model DocUpload

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Documentation";

}

<h2>Upload Documentation</h2>

<div class="alert alert-warning">
    <strong>Warning:</strong> Any existing documentation for the selected interface will be overwritten
</div>

@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Message))
{
    var alertClass = Model.Error ? "alert alert-danger" : "alert alert-success";

    <div class="@alertClass" role="alert">
        @Model.Message
    </div>
}

    <form asp-controller="Interfaces" asp-action="Documentation" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="InterfaceId"></label>
        <select asp-for="InterfaceId"  asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Interfaces, "Key", "Value"))"  >
            <option value="-1">Choose ...</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="InterfaceId" class="text-danger"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="Document" class="form-control-file" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Document" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>

</form>
```

Model:

```
public class DocUpload
{

    public Dictionary<int,string> Interfaces { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a document to upload.")]
    public IFormFile Document { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    [Display(Name = "Interface")]
    [Range(0, 100000, ErrorMessage = "You must select an interface to associate the document to.")]
    public int InterfaceId { get; set; }

    public bool Error { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `FileShare.None`? (`new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this error, it is caused by that you did not dispose the file stream.

Try code below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Documentation(DocUpload document)
{
    if (document.Document != null)
    {
        // do other validations on your model as needed
        try
        {
            string fileName = "Interface-" + document.InterfaceId + "-Documentation" +
                                    Path.GetExtension(document.Document.FileName);
            string doucumentationPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "documentation");
            string filePath = Path.Combine(doucumentationPath, fileName);
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await document.Document.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
            string fileUrl = "~/documentation/" + fileName;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            document.Error = true;
            document.Message = "The has been a problem uploading the documentation:" + Environment.NewLine +
                                e.Message;
        }
        //to do save to db  
    }
    return View(document);
}
```

Comment: Solves the problem regarding file locking but not why the 404